# Specify HICON index when calling CreateBitmapFromHIcon in WIC

Tags: c++, winapi

According to documentation [ExtractIconEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extracticonexa) returns a pointer to an array of HICON. How can I specify which item in this array to use when passing to [CreateBitmapFromHICON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicimagingfactory-createbitmapfromhicon).

```
#include <iostream>
        #include <Windows.h>
        #include <Wincodec.h>
        #pragma comment(lib,"Windowscodecs.lib")

HICON hiconLarge = NULL;
HICON hiconSmall = NULL;

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    double x, y;

    IWICImagingFactory* piFactory = NULL;
    IWICBitmap* piBitmap = NULL;

    //Create the COM imaging factory.
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWICImagingFactory,
        (LPVOID*)&piFactory);

    UINT nIcons;
    nIcons = ExtractIconEx(L"c:\\windows\\system32\\shell32.dll",
        -1,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        0);

        ExtractIconEx(L"c:\\windows\\system32\\shell32.dll",
        0,
        &hiconLarge,
        &hiconSmall,
        nIcons);

    std::cout << nIcons << " icons found." << std::endl;

    HRESULT hResult = piFactory->CreateBitmapFromHICON(hiconLarge, &piBitmap);
    if (hResult == S_OK)
    {
        piBitmap->GetResolution(&x, &y);
        std::cout << "Resolution x=" << x << " y=" << y << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to extract an icon whose resource ID you know? If so, there's a relatively simple answer.

Comment: My eventual goal is to extract all icons and save them to png. I was hoping to at least get this working before I further explored how to use wic to do the actual conversion.

Comment: Then just loop through the returned `HICON` array(s), using an index from `0` to `nIcons-1`. I'm not 100% sure, but I *think* the icons will be returned in increasing order of their resource IDs.

Comment: HICONs are not what you want if you are building a icon extractor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate enough space to `nIcons` `HICON` values before your second call to `ExtractIconEx`, so `hiconLarge` and `hiconSmall` should be pointers to HICON objets (`HICON *`).  Currently you only have enough space for one.  Then you access the values like you normally do with arrays.